# idea9.0.3 commit

Tags: intellij-idea

I use idea 9.0.3 and I want to commit few my application's files to SVN.

Please can anyone tell me step by step what I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add version control to the project, using the 'version control' menu option at the top.  I have IDEA 10, so it might be different, but in the menu, there is an 'import into version control' option.  So add your SVN repo there.

once you have done that you can right click on any file or directory, go to the 'Subversion' option, and do svn operations on the file.

I use command+k on my mac to automatically start the commit process.  The only thing I need to remember is to add files when they are first created, else they don't get committed.

EDIT -- You might have failed to add svn to the project -- did you enter your credentials?  I assumed there was already an svn repo for your project.  You don't see something like:
[image]

Comment: Than you for replying.                                              In my 'version control' there is not 'import into version control', but there are 'import into subversion' and 'import into CVS..'  I have tried 'import into subversion', but after it when I right clicked on my files, there was not subversion...